# ¿Cómo establecer Python 3.9 por defecto en Linux Ubuntu?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

El objetivo es que cuando ejecute en la consola de linux-Ubuntu:
`python --version` ó `python -V`  omitiendo el `python3`

El resultado que arroje sea:

```
Python 3.9.0
```

Ya que es la versión que me piden en el trabajo

Ahorita estoy usando Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, y cuando ejecuto `python --version` me muestra esto:

```
Orden «python» no encontrada. Quizá quiso decir:
  la orden «python» del paquete deb «python3»
  la orden «python» del paquete deb «python-ispython3»
```

Y ejecuto el comando `python3 --version` me muestra esta versión:

```
Python 3.10.4
```

Comment: Tienes que crear un "vínculo simbólico". Primero ejecuta el comando `which python3` para ver en qué carpeta se encuentra el ejecutable. Pongamos como ejemplo que te de algo como `/usr/bin/python3`. Luego solo tendrías que crear el vínculo con `ln -sf /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python`. Preguntame si algo no quedó claro.

Comment: me salió: Permiso denegado

Comment: Pues usa `sudo`. Eso es conocimiento básico de manejo de Linux

Comment: ok, soy novato en linux, es la primera vez que lo estoy usando

Comment: listo! ingreso `python --version` y me da: `python 3.10.4`

Comment: La terminal es una herramienta muy poderosa en Linux, te recomiendo aprender al menos los comandos más básicos. Vale la pena.

Comment: Ok ok. ya quedó, solo existe una alternativa de `python3.9` que al momento de ejecutar `python --versio` ó `python -V` muestra: `Python 3.9.13`

Comment: ¿Alguna razón para quedarte en 3.9 en lugar de 3.10?

Comment: Python es un componente importante en Linux y no es recomendable modificarlo. Pero creo que puedes tener varias versiones instaladas. Revisa [este artículo](https://hackersandslackers.com/multiple-python-versions-ubuntu-20-04/) tal vez pueda servirte.